# Circle Cipher Program

Tags: javascript

I am working on creating a program to encrypt a message. One of the functions I was planning on running the code through is a circle cipher. It hasn't been working and I'm unsure as to why. At certain times the program will return the correct letters and at others it won't change anything and returns the same character that was input. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
function circle(message, rotate) {
var alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
for(i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
    for (i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
        if (message[i] == alphabet[i]) {
            message[i] = alphabet[i + rotate];
            break;
        }
    }
} 
return message;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spot at least three bugs in your code:

- You use the variable `i` twice. You should use another variable name for the inner loop.
- You have to use remainder (modulus) operator to get the value `i + rotate` modulo 26.
- Strings are immutable. So you can't change individual characters of a string.

Comment: You are correct on the first two and I forgot to mention I'm feeding this function an array not a string. Thanks for your help it is working now.